# What effects does the Compass have in ActRaiser?

Tags: actraiser

I've been playing a lot of old SNES games on my Android phone recently, and have currently picked [ActRaiser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActRaiser) up again. I thought I had maxed this game out as a kid but I want to replay it and make sure I never missed anything.

I just got the Compass from Bloodpool. I think I always used to give that to Marahna... but I forgot what it did. I read online people saying it should be used in Fillmore instead. Where can the Compass be used and what effects does it have? Should it be used in Marahna or Fillmore? Can it be used anywhere else, like Northwall?

Comment: I loved the ActRaiser games.  So original!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You receive the compass in [Bloodpool](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/ActRaiser/Bloodpool).

"You do not need to use the compass at Marahna in order to obtain the magic aura - dropping the tablet and hitting the bush with lightning are sufficient. Using the compass there gets you an MP." - [Kenneth G. Kroenlein](http://shrines.rpgclassics.com/snes/actraiser/tips.shtml)

Instead, use it at [Fillmore](http://www.ign.com/cheats/games/actraiser-snes-7672) to get an extra life.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Hmmm, I'm not sure which would be better. I think I'd rather have one extra MP than an extra life!

Comment: Any idea if it can be used in Northwall?

Comment: Been forever since I played, but the wiki makes no mention of it: http://strategywiki.org/wiki/ActRaiser/Northwall

Comment: I just tried. You can only use it in Marahna or Fillmore, anywhere else the angel says "This will only benefit lands which rely on fishing"... *even after Northwall says they started a Fishery!* (Boo, I was hoping they'd use the compass and discover something cool)

Answer (score -1):

You can also use it in Bloodpool to get a Source of Life.

source: [RPGClassics.com - Actraiser: Items](http://shrines.rpgclassics.com/snes/actraiser/items.shtml)

Comment: You receive the compass in Bloodpool. If you try to use it here, the angel says "These people already understand the usage of the compass". That site is riddled with incorrect information... to get the extra life the compass must be used in *Fillmore*

Comment: The best part is that the listing for the sources of life under it is correct - the page isn't even self-consistent.